# Limit in foreach?

Tags: php, select, foreach, limit, scandir

I didnt found a solution for my problem. With the following code I scan files in a folder. I see only 601 entries. Is there any limit in foreach, select or scandir?

```
<?php
$ordner = "../picture/";
$alledateien = scandir($ordner);
sort($alledateien);
foreach ($alledateien as $datei) {
$dateiinfo = pathinfo($ordner."/".$datei);
$size = ceil(filesize($ordner."/".$datei)/1024); 
if ($datei != "." && $datei != ".."  && $datei != "_notes") { 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $dateiinfo['filename'] . "." . $dateiinfo['extension']; ?>"><?php echo $dateiinfo['filename']; ?> (<?php echo $dateiinfo['extension']; ?> | <?php echo $size ; ?>kb)</option>
<?php
}};
?>
```

Comment: `foreach` will traverse through everything limited by the size of what you pass it.  Look at the control structure [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) where you can set a limit

Comment: I would use `glob`

Comment: Hi Aaron. Thank you for your fast answer. I wouldnt a limit.. I would see all entries. But I see only 599.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start from

```
for($k=2;$k<count($alledateien);$k++){
$dateiinfo = pathinfo($ordner."/".$alledateien[$k]);
// .. Your Code
}
```

Limit is when the condition gets satisfies . Depends on you how you set it in a loop .

If you give a `print_r($alledateien)` you will get to see two extra files `.` and `..` , those are `current directory` and `parent directory`. To ignore start the loop from 2.

Comment: Ok I know what you mean. But how you would realise that with my code?

Comment: I did the same thing few hours back lol :) remove that sort thing . is your count 601? if not then i will edit my code to remove the . and .. in the array

Comment: Haha nice :) I removed the sort thing, but without any changes. Yes you have right - it stops after 601 entries.

Comment: Sure, but my problem is not resolved :S Your idea with remove the sort was not the solution.

Comment: Did u take a look at my answer? Ur looking at the comment .. did u try the loop from 2?

Comment: I have only to copy for($k=2;$k<count($alledateien);$k++) at the beginning of my code or what I have to do?

Comment: Thank you. No it loads very long and show me the same 601 entries how before.

Comment: Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => 01_ABSA_Johannesburg.jpg [3] => ... weytec.jpg [602] => world.jpg )

Comment: By looking at ur code and what i suggested its fine . array ending on 602 has a size of 603 , if loop starts from 2 ends in 603 so it should load 601 entries

Comment: You have right - the entries was only unsorted. Thanks alot. :)